# What photos are these and where do they come from - I haven't added any

Tags: macos, iphone, ios, photos

Every time I plug in my iPhone and sync, I get the message **"Syncing and Copying Photos"** even though I *haven't added* any photos to sync. Any idea where they might be coming from?

[image]

Comment: I've had similar issues with music, where the same songs sync every time. Never did run down a fix or why it is happening. It may be the same issue here, but with photos.

Comment: Do you use WhatsApp or other messaging systems that can send photos or gifs over?

Comment: no over the air photos stuff or whatsapp or messaging systems